# Logic App - Expression to get a particular substring from a json

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have out form one of the tasks in Logic App:

```
{
"headers": {
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
"body": {
    "systemAlertId": "....",
    "endTimeUtc": null,
    "entities": [
        {
            "$id": "us_1",
            "hostName": "...",
            "azureID": "someID",
            "type": "host"
        },
        {
            "$id": "us_2",
            "address": "fwdedwedwedwed",
            "location": {
                "countryCode": "",
            },
            "type": "ip"
        },
    ], 
}
}
```

I need initialize some variable named resourceID that contains value **someID** which is read from above example.

Value **someID** will always be found in the first member of Entities array, in that case I guess need to use function **first**

Any idea how expression of Initial variable should look?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the mentioned data you are receiving from Http trigger, I have used Parse JSON in order to get the inner values of the mentioned JSON. Here is how you can do it.

[image]

[image]

and now you can initialize the resourceID using 'Initialise variable' connector and set its value to azureID as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: yes, it worked, parsing was a bit complicated, but finally it worked, thank for help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Parse JSON action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action).

> To reference or access properties in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) content, you can create user-friendly fields or tokens for those properties by using the **Parse JSON** action. That way, you can select those properties from the dynamic content list when you specify inputs for your logic app. For this action, you can either provide a JSON schema or generate a JSON schema from your sample JSON content or payload.

With the information in the JSON available in an object, you can more easily access it.